# LatexDraw issues when drawing arcs

Tags: packages

Recently updated some of the packages in Latex.

This resulted in Latexdraw errors when drawing arcs and text.

Any notes about Latex updates or packages that cause problems in Latexdraw?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a small complete document that shows the problem (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Add it to your posting using the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/333157/edit). Your posting currently contains too little information to say anything meaningful.

Comment: Could you also say exactly what errors you get?

Comment: when adding a text string, a large box was introduced, making very difficult to place the text in the location I wanted.

Comment: also, when drawing arcs, the box with the controls for the arc were strange and not behaving well.

Comment: after reviewing what I did during package update in Latex, I realized that perhaps LatexDraw needed some references to the packages that had been updated. So I added the same list of \usepackage{} commands that I have in my master document, and this fixed the problem.

Comment: Now Latexdraw behaves almost as it did before this package update. The only issue remaining is the beginning and ending angle in the parameters for the arc. Everything else has returned to normal. I would still like to have additional documentation about what default packages are used by Latexdraw when started, and if there is any way to configure it for those packages, but without having them added during Export to pstricks (I do have to comment these before adding the figures to my master document)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding text figures, a recent PSTricks update broke their cropping. A workaround has been proposed in LaTeXDraw to fix this issues. You can test this fix by using the latest development version by following the "Nightly builds" link provided at: http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/.

Regarding the arc issue, I suggest you to look at this web page (https://github.com/arnobl/latexdraw/wiki/Manual#how-to-report-a-bug) to provide more information on your issue (in particular an SVG document that can be used to reproduce the problem).